# Two model forms one view form validation not displaying

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a template that renders two forms handled through one view. The first form "store_form" is a Bootstrap modal and in most cases the user will not need open it and submit data to it. The second form "wo_form" will be submitted separately from store_form. When I submit to store_form, inline is_valid() validation error messages are properly displayed. How do I have the wo_form display validation error messages if the fields aren't filled out properly?

Also, is there a way to reinput the data previously put into the wo_form if a user submits to store_form? It currently does a redirect back and the data already put into wo_form is lost.

views.py:

```
def work_order_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'store_form' in request.POST:
            store_form = StoreForm(request.POST)
            wo_form = WorkOrderForm()
            if store_form.is_valid():
               store_form.save()
        else:
            store_form = StoreForm()
            wo_form = WorkOrderForm(request.POST)
            if wo_form.is_valid():
               wo_form.save()
    else: 
        wo_form = WorkOrderForm()
        store_form = StoreForm()
    return render_to_response('work_order_form.html', RequestContext(request, {
        'wo_form': wo_form,
        'store_form': store_form,
    }))
```

My forms.py is very basic:

```
class WorkOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = WorkOrder
    labels = {
        'name': 'Work Order',
        'nte': 'NTE',
    }
    widgets = {
        'date_received': BootstrapDateInput(),
        'trip_date': BootstrapDateInput(),
    }

class StoreForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
    model = Store
```

work_order_form.html (confusing due to me wanting to avoid the default form display):

```
<div class="row">
    <form class="form-{{ layout }}" action="" method="post" name="form-type"          value="wo_form">
    <div class="span4 offset1"> 

        {% csrf_token %}

        {{ wo_form.name.label_tag }}
        {{ wo_form.name }}

        <div class="row">
            <div class="span1">
                <label for="wo_form.complete.label" class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox"> {{ wo_form.complete.label }}
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="span1">
                <label for="wo_form.emergency.label" class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox"> {{ wo_form.emergency.label }}
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="span2">
                <label for="wo_form.after_hours.label" class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox"> {{ wo_form.after_hours.label }}
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>


        {{ wo_form.date_received.label_tag }}
        {{ wo_form.date_received }}

        {{ wo_form.trip_date.label_tag }}
        {{ wo_form.trip_date }}

        {{ wo_form.time_in.label_tag }}
        {{ wo_form.time_in }}

        {{ wo_form.time_out.label_tag }}
        {{ wo_form.time_out }}

        {{ wo_form.total_hours.label_tag }}
        {{ wo_form.total_hours }}

        {{ wo_form.nte.label_tag }}
        {{ wo_form.nte }}

        {{ wo_form.instructions.label_tag }}
        {{ wo_form.instructions }} 

        <label for="wo_form.completed_on_trip.label" class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox"> {{ wo_form.completed_on_trip.label }}
        </label>
        <input type="submit" name="wo_form" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>


    <div class="span4"> 

        {{ wo_form.location.label_tag }}
        {{ wo_form.location }}
        <br>
    </form>
        <a data-toggle="modal" class="contact" href="#storeModal" title="Edit">New Store</a>

        <div class="modal hide" id="storeModal">
        <form class="well contact-form" method="post" action="" name="form-type" value="store_form">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h3>Editing Store</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
               {% csrf_token %}
               {{ store_form|as_bootstrap }}
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
               <input name="store_form" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save" />
               <input name="cancel" class="btn" type="submit" value="Cancel"/>
          </div>
        </form>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if any other resources would be of help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include field errors when you manually render the form in the template.

```
<div class="span1">
    {{ wo_form.subject.errors }}

    <label for="wo_form.complete.label" class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox"> {{ wo_form.complete.label }}
    </label>
</div>
```

For more information, see the docs on [customizing the form template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template%5d). Since you are using bootstrap, you may find [crispy forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/) useful. It makes it easy to render forms that look good with bootstrap.

Comment: This was it! Thank you. I tried to get crispy forms to work alongside Django-Bootstrap-Toolkit, but no luck. Perhaps I'll give it another go.

Answer (score 1):

Form creation:

```
wo_form = WorkOrderForm(prefix="wo")
store_form = StoreForm(prefix="store")
```

In template use one  tag to post two forms in one time, and then in view:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    store_form = StoreForm(request.POST, prefix="store")
    wo_form = WorkOrderForm(request.POST, prefix="wo")
    if 'store_form' in request.POST:            
        if store_form.is_valid():
           store_form.save()
    elif wo_form.is_valid():
           wo_form.save()
....
```

Comment: Still won't work. What is difference between doing this and my current approach? Perhaps I am doing the template wrong. I have this: <form class="form-{{ layout }}" action="" method="post" name="form" value="form"> #all of my stuff </form>

Comment: This also removed the styling widgets for some reason.

Comment: on this approch you chage <form method="post" action="">{{ store_form }} {{ wo_form }}</form> so in request.POST there will be fields from store_form and wo_form, and if you want reinput data filled in wo_form you have to add it to post. Prefix is need to have data for two forms in one post. Selection which form is filled is done by checking which submit button is press.